# Setup karma unit tests with pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner, pouchdb

I want to setup unit tests for my angular app that uses pouchdb + angular-pouchdb.
But when i run:

`karma start karma.conf.js`

I get the following error:

> PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'eventEmitter[method].bind(eventEmitter)')
>
> at .../public/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb-nightly.js:5758

The angular app runs well in the browser, and all my karma.conf.js file includes the same dependencies, so i don't understand why the pouchdb-nightly.js would have an undefined function.
What am I missing?

Comment: [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is not implemented in phantomjs. I'm not familiar with karma and cannot recommend a solution.

Comment: .bind is called by the pouchdb library. So this would mean that Pouchdb does not support PhantomJs browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common error: PhantomJS has not implemented Function.prototype.bind ([here's the bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522)), so you need the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

Or you can get by by just shimming Function.prototype.bind instead of including the whole es5-shim library. Here's an example (taken from [here](https://github.com/pouchdb/plugin-seed/blob/master/test/bind-polyfill.js)):

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  // minimal polyfill for phantomjs; in the future, we should do ES5_SHIM=true like pouchdb
  if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
      if (typeof this !== "function") {
        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
      }

      var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
          fToBind = this,
          fNOP = function () {},
          fBound = function () {
            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                   ? this
                   : oThis,
                   aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
          };

      fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
      fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

      return fBound;
    };
  }
})();
```

Comment: Where does the shim go? How would you use it?

Comment: put it in a script tag before pouchdb

Comment: or I guess in the case of Karma, you put it in the `files` list before pouchdb.

Comment: since the projects already has es5-shim through bower, including it karma allows it to work like a charm. i'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me with a jasmine/PhantomJS test using RequireJS and PouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522) is fixed in PhantomJS 2+. So an update of the Phantom node modules should do it.

Tested with the following versions of test-related modules in `package.json`

```
"karma": "0.13.21",
"karma-jasmine": "0.3.7",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.0",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.3",
```